# how to fix the worrd in the table column?

Tags: python, pandas, string, beautifulsoup, python-3.6

I am extracting a table from a website. I tried already with Pandas and BeautifulSoup.

Here is an example of a code i tried:

```py
    res = requests.get("https://www.dasoertliche.de/Themen/Postleitzahlen/Berlin.html")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content,'lxml')   
    table = soup.find_all('table')[0]    
    df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]    
    df
```

the website table looks like this
[image: Screen shot from the website]
my results look like this
[image]

I want the word in the third column to be separated by a comma
any ideas?!

Comment: Try `pd.read_html("https://www.dasoertliche.de/Themen/Postleitzahlen/Berlin.html")[0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
html = requests.get('https://www.dasoertliche.de/Themen/Postleitzahlen/Berlin.html').text.replace("<br/>", ', ')
df = pd.read_html(html, attrs={'id': 'tl-plz'})[0]
df
```

The problem is `<br/>` inside table, so we just get rid of it first.

Comment: i did not try the other suggestion but this one works just fine for me

Answer (score 0):

If you will see the HTML response. You will find `<br/>` tags inside that column for showing each in next line. YOu can simply replace `<br/>` with **`,`**

```
res = requests.get("https://www.dasoertliche.de/Themen/Postleitzahlen/Berlin.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content,'lxml')   
table = str(soup.find_all('table')[0]) 

#replce <br> with comma
table = table.replace("<br/>", ",")

df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]    
df
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I dont't know if it is an option, but you may try with regex- if the pattern is fixed, i.e. all separate words start with capital, and no other capital characters appear within a separate string, you may try to add spaces before each capital letter:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    df['Ortsteil'][i] = re.sub(r"(\w)([A-Z])", r"\1 \2", df['Ortsteil'][i])
```

Or without looping the df:

```
df['Ortsteil'] = df['Ortsteil'].apply(lambda x: re.sub('(\w)([A-Z])', r"\1 \2", str(x)))
```